# How to make sure functions finish before next start? Flutter initState()

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, initialization

i am encountering error, which I believe is related to initState() function, I am using firebase and load data from it, and I need to ensure that `initializeData();` is done before   `initializeSorting()` starts. How can I do that? Tried async await but didnt find solution.

```html
class _TasksListState extends State<TasksList> {
  List<Task> tasks = [];
  Set<int> usedIds = Set();
  late String taskTitle;
  late final String user;
  late CollectionReference _collectionRef;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = widget.user;
    taskTitle = widget.taskTitle;

    _collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(user)
        .collection('Tasks');

    initializeData();
    initializeSorting();
  }
```

Comment: `initState`cannot be asynchronous.  Do your asynchronous initialization in a separate `async` function, make that function `await` its asynchronous operations so that run sequentially, and then make your `build`method use a `FutureBuilder` that waits for the `Future` of your asynchronous initialization.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by doing something like this,

```
       void callMe() async{
        await initializeData();
        initializeSorting();
       }

       @override
       void initState() {
       callMe();
       super.initState();
       }
```

Note: you will have to return `Future` from the `initializeData()` function, because you can't use `await` on a void function,

Comment: A lot of things are not right here: Code is not well formatted, you are awaiting calls of functions that are not async and  you have async functions that don't return a Future.

Comment: Oh common man, make sure to read the whole answer, i mentioned in the last with `Note` to return Future from that function, My aim was just to suggest the way to achieve this questions solution not to provide the whole solution each step by step.