# How to ensure code executes in proper order? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization

1. I am getting error `LateInitializationError: Field 'sorting' has not been initialized.` In my code I need to ensure that `build` executes after every function in init is done. Init of `sorting` happens in `initializeSorting()` function, but apparently `build` is executes before `sorting` is initialized.
2. Also I do not know why but prints of `tasks` prints empty lists `[]` which they shouldn't, meanwhile `user` and `taskTitle` prints are ok. I am passing the data from another widget like this: `TaskSortWidget(onSort: sortTasks, user: user, taskTitle: taskTitle, tasks: tasks)`. Already tried approaches with nullables but didn't work. Completely no idea why both `widget.tasks` and `tasks` are empty.
3. I will highly appreciate any help.

## FULL WIDGET_SORT CODDE

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:taskease/classes/task.dart';

enum SortOrder {
  Ascending,
  Descending,
}

enum TaskSortingCriteria {
  Priority,
  DueDate,
  FromDate,
}

class TaskSortWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(List<Task>) onSort;
  final String user;
  final String taskTitle;
  final List<Task> tasks;

  TaskSortWidget(
      {required this.onSort,
      required this.user,
      required this.taskTitle,
      required this.tasks});

  @override
  _TaskSortWidgetState createState() => _TaskSortWidgetState();
}

class _TaskSortWidgetState extends State<TaskSortWidget> {
  bool loading = false;
  late List<Task> tasks;
  late CollectionReference _collectionRef;
  late final String taskTitle;
  late final String user;
  late Map<String, dynamic> sorting;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      user = widget.user;
      taskTitle = widget.taskTitle;
    });
    tasks = widget.tasks;
    _collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(user)
        .collection('Tasks');
    initializeSorting();
  }

  Future<void> initializeSorting() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    DocumentSnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.doc(taskTitle).get();

    if (querySnapshot.exists) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = querySnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      setState(() {
        sorting = data['sorting'];

      });
    } else {
      print(
          '(sort widget, this message should never show!) Sorting does not exist. Creating one...'); //this else will never execute
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(user)
          .collection('Tasks')
          .doc(taskTitle)
          .set({
        'sorting': {
          '_currentSortOrderPriority': {2, 'Ascending'},
          '_currentSortOrderDueDate': {0, 'Ascending'},
          '_currentSortOrderFromDate': {1, 'Ascending'},
        }
      }, SetOptions(merge: true));
    }
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });
    sortTasks();
  }

  void sortTasks() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sorting.length; i++) {
      for (var entry in sorting.entries) {
        if (entry.value[0] == i) {
          SortOrder sortOrder = entry.value[1] == 'Ascending'
              ? SortOrder.Ascending
              : SortOrder.Descending;
          switch (entry.key) {
            case '_currentSortOrderPriority':
              tasks.sort((a, b) =>
                  a.priority.index.compareTo(b.priority.index) *
                  (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? 1 : -1));
              break;
            case '_currentSortOrderDueDate':
              tasks.sort((a, b) =>
                  a.dueDate!.compareTo(b.dueDate!) *
                  (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? 1 : -1));
              break;
            case '_currentSortOrderFromDate':
              tasks.sort((a, b) =>
                  a.fromDate!.compareTo(b.fromDate!) *
                  (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? 1 : -1));
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void _cycleSortOrder(TaskSortingCriteria sortingCriteria) {
    setState(() {
      switch (sortingCriteria) {
        case TaskSortingCriteria.Priority:
          sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][1] =
              sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][1] == 'Ascending'
                  ? 'Descending'
                  : 'Ascending';
          switch (sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][0]) {
            case 0:
              sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][0] = 2;
              sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][0]--;
              sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][0]--;
              break;
            case 1:
              sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][0] = 2;
              if (sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][0] == 2)
                sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][0] = 1;
              else
                sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][0] = 1;
              break;
            case 2:
              break;
          }
          break;
        case TaskSortingCriteria.DueDate:
          sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][1] =
              sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][1] == 'Ascending'
                  ? 'Descending'
                  : 'Ascending';
          switch (sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][0]) {
            case 0:
              sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][0] = 2;
              sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][0]--;
              sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][0]--;
              break;
            case 1:
              sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][0] = 2;
              if (sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][0] == 2)
                sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][0] = 1;
              else
                sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][0] = 1;
              break;
            case 2:
              break;
          }
          break;
        case TaskSortingCriteria.FromDate:
          sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][1] =
              sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][1] == 'Ascending'
                  ? 'Descending'
                  : 'Ascending';
          switch (sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][0]) {
            case 0:
              sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][0] = 2;
              sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][0]--;
              sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][0]--;
              break;
            case 1:
              sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][0] = 2;
              if (sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][0] == 2)
                sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][0] = 1;
              else
                sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][0] = 1;
              break;
            case 2:
              break;
          }
          break;
      }
    });
    updateSorting();
    sortTasks();
    widget.onSort(tasks);
  }

  Future<void> updateSorting() async {
    await _collectionRef.doc(taskTitle).set({
      'sorting': toJson(),
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      '_currentSortOrderPriority': {
        sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][0],
        sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][1],
      },
      '_currentSortOrderDueDate': {
        sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][0],
        sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][1],
      },
      '_currentSortOrderFromDate': {
        sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][0],
        sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][1],
      },
    };
  }

  Widget _buildSortButton(String label, TaskSortingCriteria sortingCriteria) {
    print(sorting);
    IconData icon;
    switch (sortingCriteria) {
      case TaskSortingCriteria.Priority:
        icon = sorting['_currentSortOrderPriority'][1] == SortOrder.Ascending
            ? Icons.arrow_upward
            : Icons.arrow_downward;
        break;
      case TaskSortingCriteria.DueDate:
        icon = sorting['_currentSortOrderDueDate'][1] == SortOrder.Ascending
            ? Icons.arrow_upward
            : Icons.arrow_downward;
        break;
      case TaskSortingCriteria.FromDate:
        icon = sorting['_currentSortOrderFromDate'][1] == SortOrder.Ascending
            ? Icons.arrow_upward
            : Icons.arrow_downward;
        break;
      default:
        print('error');
        icon = Icons.error;
    }

    return ElevatedButton.icon(
      onPressed: () {
        print('sorting by $sortingCriteria');
        _cycleSortOrder(sortingCriteria);
      },
      icon: Icon(icon),
      label: Text(label),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      tasks = widget.tasks;
    });
    return loading
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        :
      Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        _buildSortButton('Sort by Priority', TaskSortingCriteria.Priority),
        SizedBox(width: 6),
        _buildSortButton('Sort by Due Date', TaskSortingCriteria.DueDate),
        SizedBox(width: 6),
        _buildSortButton('Sort by From Date', TaskSortingCriteria.FromDate),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

## WIDGET_SORT CALL FROM ANOTHER WIDGET

```
class TasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  late final String user;
  late final String taskTitle;

  TasksList({required this.user, required this.taskTitle});

  @override
  State<TasksList> createState() => _TasksListState();
}

class _TasksListState extends State<TasksList> {
  List<Task> tasks = [];
  Set<int> usedIds = Set();
  late String taskTitle;
  late final String user;
  late CollectionReference _collectionRef;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = widget.user;
    taskTitle = widget.taskTitle;

    _collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(user)
        .collection('Tasks');

    initializeData();
    initializeSorting();
  }

  Future<void> initializeSorting() async {
DocumentSnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.doc(taskTitle).get();

    if (!querySnapshot.exists) {
      print('Sorting does not exist. Creating one...');
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(user)
          .collection('Tasks').doc(taskTitle).set
        ({
        'sorting': {
          '_currentSortOrderPriority': {2, 'Ascending'},
          '_currentSortOrderDueDate': {0, 'Ascending'},
          '_currentSortOrderFromDate': {1, 'Ascending'},
        }
      }, SetOptions(merge: true));
    }
}

  Future<void> initializeData() async {
    List<Task> fetchedTasks = await initializeTasks();
    initializeUsedIds(fetchedTasks);
  }

  void initializeUsedIds(List<Task> tasks) {
    for (Task task in tasks) {
      usedIds.add(task.id);
    }
  }

  Future<List<Task>> initializeTasks() async {...}

  Future<List<Task>> getDailyTasks() async {...}

  void sortTasks(List<Task> sortedTasks){
    setState(() {
      this.tasks = sortedTasks;
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print(tasks);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(taskTitle),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TaskSortWidget(onSort: sortTasks, user: user, taskTitle: taskTitle, tasks: tasks), //calling task sort
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: tasks.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                if (index == tasks.length) {
                  return Container();
                }
    //rest of code here
    }

``
```

Comment: You can try using FutureBuilder and pass initializeSorting() in future.

Comment: [I told you what to do yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76915711/how-to-make-sure-functions-finish-before-next-start-flutter-initstate#comment135593526_76915711).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your full build code but I am assuming you are calling values that are meant to be fetched from your database in your build before the Future function is finished.

In this case you need to display your build conditionally when it is completed.

```
bool loading = false;

Future<void> initializeSorting() async {
      setState((){
        loading = true;
      });
    DocumentSnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.doc(taskTitle).get();
    if (querySnapshot.exists) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = querySnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      setState(() {
        sorting = data['sorting']; //sorting initializing here
      });
    }
      setState((){
        loading = false;
      });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build starts');
    return loading 
        ? CircularProgressIndicator() 
        : Row(...);
  }
```

Comment: WOW, it actually solved the issue. Wouldn't ever thought that would be so simple thank you!

Comment: By any chance, do you now why this code:

 ` Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build sorting widget');
    print(widget.tasks);
    print(tasks);`
    
prints correctly from 1st print: `print('build sorting widget');`
but prints nothing from 2nd:  `print(tasks);`

do I set the variables somehow wrong in initState()?

Comment: hmm i'm not sure. Did you try quitting the app and `flutter run` instead of hot reload?

Comment: I need to see how you are defining them and passing the data from the previous page. Can you edit your code to include that?

Comment: yes I will provide my full code for that widget, and where I call that widget to be built

Comment: I see how you pass it but i dont see how you define it

Comment: OK, I updated the code in question, now it contains all the function taking part in sorting stuff

Comment: from what i see, your widget.tasks list is empty until the _buildSortButton is pressed. Does it still print(widget.tasks) = [] after _buildSortButton is pressed?

Comment: If I put `print(widget.tasks)` in onPressed() it prints tasks correctly, but the thing is, I want to pass `tasks` list to sorting when clicked, and then sorting_widget makes local variable `tasks` which should be initialized like `tasks = widget.tasks` in initState(), just like `user` and `taskTitle`, but it doesnt initialize there for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254943/discussion-between-texv-and-jon).